# Convert a 1D string to a 2D array of Integers

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, multidimensional-array

I have a string and I want to convert it to a 2D array of integers. This is what I am doing:

```
String string1="[1,2,3]~[4,5,6]~[7,8,9]~";

//Putting each element into an array of strings

String stringArray[]=string1.split("~");

//Determining the number of columns for the 2D array

int countints=0;
Scanner ins = new Scanner(stringArray[0]);
while (ins.hasNext()){
    countints+=1;
    ins.next();
}

//converting into an array of integers

int intArray[][]=new int[stringArray.length][countints];
```

Here I'm stuck as how to parse each integer into the 2D array.

Comment: you need to further isolate number from `"[1,2,3]"` checkout `Matcher` class and see `Integer.parseInt()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String string1="[1,2,3]~[4,5,6]~[7,8,9]~";
String string2 = string1.replace("[","").replace("]","");

for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++)
{
   String s = stringArray[i].substring(1, stringArray[i].length()-1);
   String[] elementArray = s.split(",");
   for(int j = 0; j < elementArray.length; j++)
   {
       int val = Integer.parseInt(elementArray[j]);
       intArray[i][j] = val;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have initialized the 2D array, you need to parse each element in `stringArray` by getting rid of trailing and leading **'[', ']'** bracket pairs and splitting it with **","** and parse each element of the split string into Integer and put that int value to the given 2d array at correct postion.

**EDIT: WORKING SOLUTION**

```
    String string1="[1,2,3]~[4,5,6]~[7,8,9]~";

    String stringArray[]=string1.split("~");

    int countints = stringArray[0].substring(1, stringArray[0].length()-1).split(",").length;

    int intArray[][]=new int[stringArray.length][countints];

    for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++)
    {
       String s = stringArray[i].substring(1, stringArray[i].length()-1);
       String[] elementArray = s.split(",");
       for(int j = 0; j < elementArray.length; j++)
       {
           int val = Integer.parseInt(elementArray[j]);
           intArray[i][j] = val;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Careful - `parseInt` can throw a [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt).

Comment: Make sure you don't have any compile errors. Also, I noticed there is a bug in your code when you calculate countints. It essentially gets the value as 0. Make sure it has the value 3, and all should be good. I ran the program and it gives the correct output.

Comment: Your code doesn't works if there's some number with more than one digit.

Answer (score 0):

For a totally dynamic array:

```
String string1 = "[1,2,3]~[4,5,6]~[7,8,9]~";
String[] lines = string1.split("(^|~)\\[");
int[][] array = new int[lines.length][0];

Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

int lineIndex = 0;
for (String line : lines) {

    //if the row size is dynamic
    Matcher m1 = pat.matcher(line);
    int rowSize = 0;
    while (m1.find())
        rowSize++;

    array[lineIndex] = new int[rowSize];

    int colIndex = 0;
    Matcher m2 = pat.matcher(line);
    while (m2.find()) {
        array[lineIndex][colIndex++] = Integer.parseInt(m2.group());
    }
    lineIndex++;
}

for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++){
    for(int j=0; j<array[i].length;j++){
        System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

It prints:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean solution that works.  I started working on it before I got through all of the other answers, so my apologies if it doesn't meaningfully add to what is already here:

```
public class SO {
    public static int[][] parse(String input) {
        String[] rows = input.split("~");
        int[][] ints = new int[rows.length][];
        int j = 0;
        for(String row : rows) {
            String[] cols = row.substring(1, row.length()-1).split(",");
            int k = 0;
            ints[j] = new int[cols.length];
            for(String col : cols) {
                ints[j][k++] = Integer.parseInt(col);
            }
            j++;
        }

        return ints;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int[] row : parse("[1,2,3]~[4,5,6]~[7,8,9]~")) {
            for(int col : row) {
                System.out.print(","+col);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the output:

```
,1,2,3
,4,5,6
,7,8,9
```

As for error checking you should decide upfront how you want to handle error checking, As this is written a single invalid int will throw an exception, which I think is the correct behavior.  Malformed rows on the other hand might give unpredictable output (which I would say is wrong if the input has even the slightest potential to be malformed).